# Can dialogflow inline editor handle multiple different functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a dialogflow agent that that can do the following (through dialogflow fulfillment inline editor) :

**1) Change calendar a dates (headed by the function makeappointment)**

**2) Book a reservation time (headed by the function makeboooking)**

**3) Change information in the firestore database**

(1 and 2 both change events on a Google Calendar, so mechanically speaking they are the same but the intents are different).

The problem I am having is I can't seem to get all three of these functions working at the same time. I can comment out 2 of them and the third will work, or comment the first and the third, and the second function will work ect.

The code is way to long to post on stackoverflow, so i made a github to post to it [here](https://github.com/lando22/dialogflowbot/blob/master/code).

How can I get all three of these functions working in the fullfilment?

Thanks for your help!

**Note**: Lines that have credentials on them have been taken out for security reasons. Please trust me that I have the correct credentials in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.  I'd recommend looking at [Dialogflow's examples](https://github.com/dialogflow) to get an understand of how you should structure your code.  For starters:

- In your code you have multiple intent maps and `handleRequest` method calls. There should only be one intent map and one `handleRequest` method call per Dialogflow agent.
- You have multiple `exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment` statements and there should only be one

You may want to [checkout Firebase's functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to get a better understanding of how they work (this is the product powering Dialogflow's inline editor feature.